# Simultaneously insert 2 rows of data into the same model item ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is possible to add data in same form, in same model item but different data like this?

See `Kodeakun` model item in the screenshot I attached. Sorry my English is bad.

My model class:

```
public class Transaksi
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Kodeakun { get; set; }
    public string Keterangan { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Tanggal { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Debit { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Kredit { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Kodeakun,Keterangan,Tanggal,Debit,Kredit")] Transaksi transaksi)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                               
            var debit = new Transaksi
            {
                Kodeakun = transaksi.Kodeakun,
                Keterangan = transaksi.Keterangan,
                Tanggal = transaksi.Tanggal,
                Debit = transaksi.Debit,
                Kredit = 0
            };

            var kredit = new Transaksi
            {
                Kodeakun = transaksi.Kodeakun,
                Keterangan = transaksi.Keterangan,
                Tanggal = transaksi.Tanggal,
                Debit = 0,
                Kredit = transaksi.Kredit
            };

            _context.Add(debit);
            _context.Add(kredit);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
}
```

Here the screenshot:

[image: From Here]

[image: To Here]

And I ended like this:

[image: My currently]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can do this by making a `ViewModel` and adding two properties of `Transaksi` class in it.

```
public class TransactionVM
{
    public Transaksi First {get; set;}
    public Transaksi Second {get; set;}
}
```

Now in your Create view, you can bind `TransactionVM` model instead of `Transaksi` model. And now your create method signature should look like this.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TransactionVM transaction)
```

And you can get both entries by
    `transaction.First` and `transaction.Second`.

Comment: i'm sorry but, it got error
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you bind your Create view with `TransactionVM` and also name input fields properly?

Comment: @David Budiman your Create method signature should look like that I provided in the above answer. Don't add `[Bind]` annotation in parameters.